# Really simple routing error, what am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I feel like this is a really simple error that I'm just not seeing...

Requests Controller

```
def create
    if @request.save
        redirect_to 'success'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def success
end
```

View, `requests/success.html.erb`

```
<h1> Testing, this is the Success page that should be rendered </h1>
```

Routes

```
get 'requests/new', to: 'requests#new', as: 'new_request'
post 'requests', to: 'requests#create' 
get 'requests/success', to: 'requests#success'
```

Now however, when I go through a successful create, I don't render the success page. Instead it appears to be trying to take me someplace weird. Here's the log output:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000success
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
[2014-06-25 10:49:24] ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part: localhost:3000success (or bad hostname?)
```

NOTE that if in the controller I change the successful redirect to `redirect_to root_path` it does work...

Comment: render and redirect_to are not the same... in your controller try using render for both... your actual error seems to stem from the difference in syntax... if you really want to use redirect try "/requests/success"

Comment: yes but in this case, I want a `redirect_to` because I want a new request to be generated and the existing variables lost. anyways, i fixed it, see answer below

Comment: yeah I figured as much after I noticed the success method in your controller... redirect_to serves up a 302 with a new path and so basically must match a path in your routes... I still maintain that "/requests/success" would have done what you were expecting... but rendering a separate action is probably a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your route to

```
get 'requests/success', to: 'request#success', as: 'success'
```

then inside your controller you can have

```
def create
  if @request.save
    redirect_to success_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Also in your routes you have `'requests#success'`, `'requests#create'` you should change them to `'request#success'` and `'request#create'` for more information refer [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Comment: I would add that you should be sure to return after your redirect so as to avoid the "multiple renders" error. So, `redirect_to(success_path) and return`.

Comment: @SteveRoss there's an if else block so *if request is saved it'll redirect to success_path and if it doesn't then it will simply render new action* and there **isn't anything else other than if-else block** so return is not needed

Comment: This worked, but I'm going to accept @Acacia's answer as it jives better with how I like to write code (without the `_path` monikers). Voted up! Interested... does this imply that Rails only allows you to use `' '` to enclose its predefined actions, e.g., new, create, edit, update, destroy, index, show? And everything else you need to specify yourself?

Comment: @james for rendering refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: @james since you are saving your record it'll be better if you redirect to a path rather than render an action and in case a save fails it makes sense to render new because you want your form to retain filled values

Comment: oh HAHA. That's super ironic, if you follow my convo thread with @user3334690, I was using redirect_to, I just did that thing where your mind misreads something because it already is planning on something. But the value that I got from Acacia's answer was still that `action:` is probably needed for non standard actions in Rails. I'll upvote that and make this the correct answer.

Comment: no issues you can accept whichever you think is best solution i was just trying to guide you towards right path and didn't see that thread :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller to this;

```
def create
    if @request.save
        redirect_to action: 'success'
    else
        render action: 'new'
    end
end

def success
end
```

Comment: Interested... does this imply that Rails only allows you to use `' '` to enclose its predefined actions, e.g., new, create, edit, update, destroy, index, show? And everything else you need to specify yourself?

Comment: @james, you can also do `render action: :success`

Comment: See the other convo threads on this page. I actually want a `redirect_to` in this case, because I want a new request and a complete clearing of the variables passed.

Comment: @james, made an adjustment or you!